# How to print the result of the awk command with the custom header

Tags: linux, awk, text-formatting, systemctl

am trying to print the all the running services in my machine.
For that i use the command

```
a=$(sudo systemctl list-units --type service --all | grep running | awk -v OFS='\t' '{ print $1, $2, $4 }')
```

The output of the above command is

```
    abrt-xorg.service       loaded  running
abrtd.service   loaded  running
accounts-daemon.service loaded  running
atd.service     loaded  running
auditd.service  loaded  running
avahi-daemon.service    loaded  running
bolt.service    loaded  running
chronyd.service loaded  running
colord.service  loaded  running
crond.service   loaded  running
cups.service    loaded  running
dbus.service    loaded  running
firewalld.service       loaded  running
gdm.service     loaded  running
grafana-server.service  loaded  running
gssproxy.service        loaded  running
influxdb.service        loaded  running
irqbalance.service      loaded  running
ksmtuned.service        loaded  running
libstoragemgmt.service  loaded  running
libvirtd.service        loaded  running
lvm2-lvmetad.service    loaded  running
```

First Column is the service name second column is loading status and third column is running status...

Above the output of each column i need the heading as

```
column name loading status running status
```

How can i do that...
Please help me

I ran the command `systemctl list-unit-files`

Got the output like

```
UNIT FILE                                     STATE   
proc-sys-fs-binfmt_misc.automount             static  
dev-hugepages.mount                           static  
dev-mqueue.mount                              static  
proc-fs-nfsd.mount                            static
```

Comment: Just to clarify: Are you sure this is the correct way to go? You are only listing services, not processes. Is this what you want?

Comment: @Pranki...Yup i need only the running services ...I need with the custom heading....Can u pls help me

Comment: Why don't you use `systemctl list-unit-files --state=running`? If you want only running services, there's no need to use 2 other tools.

Comment: @Puzzle Please see my edit above..I ran the command but it didn't give the output as expected

Comment: No, you ran a different command than I mentioned, if you run `systemctl list-unit-files`, you don't get only running services. Anyway, seems this is solved now :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `BEGIN` in your `awk` command to print headings:

```
systemctl list-units --type service --all | awk 'BEGIN{print "Unit State Status"};$4 ~ /^running$/{print $1,$2,$4}' | column -t
```

You can pipe this into `column -t` to get a nice readable output. You can also use `awk` instead of `grep` to check that column 4 matches `running`.

As mentioned in other comments, you could also run `systemctl list-units --type service --state=running` rather than using `grep` or `awk` to filter out the running services.

Comment: it works like a charm